# las consultas no devuelven null cuando no encuentra datos

Tags: javascript, firebase

tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una consulta en el primer caso el dato existe en el nodo y logra entrar a .on y recupero los datos, en el segundo caso el dato no existe en el nodo por lo que no alcanza a entrar a .on y no recupero ninguna informacion

```
liqui
 -KqTiAo1cC0nmASiGr94
    idLiqui: "-KqTiAkEtSrXZHoMo4I2"
    rut: "10401674-k"
    status: "listo"
```

como se aprecia en el nodo solo tengo 1 dato y es el que coincide con el primer caso, para el segundo caso ya no entra al .on

```
            vm.settlements.child('liqui')
            .orderByChild('rut')
            .equalTo(employee.rut)
            .on('child_added', function(snapshot){
                 vm.dates = snapshot.val();

            });
```

Comment: tiene rut el otro nodo?

Answer (score 0):

Así es no recuperas nada, pero si lo que quieres es un callback, para saber si no existe ninguna coincidencia te puede servir la función `.exists()`

```
{
  "name": {
           "first": "Ada",
          "last": "Lovelace"
    }
}

// Test for the existence of certain keys within a DataSnapshot
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
ref.once("value")
 .then(function(snapshot) {
   var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
   var b = snapshot.child("name").exists(); // true
   var c = snapshot.child("name/first").exists(); // true
 var d = snapshot.child("name/middle").exists(); // false
});
```